# Return Value From DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

We have a function that returns `NSAttributedString`
We want to instantiate the attributedString on the main thread
like this:

```cs
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                {
                    NSAttributedString attributedString = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, options, out dict, ref error);
                });
```

How can we return the attributedString after the dispatch async finishes

Comment: ,You can add Action in `DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync()`,if you want to return value , you can do this in this Action.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corefoundation.dispatchqueue.dispatchasync?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet

```
var attributedString= await GetAttributedStringAsync();

        public Task<NSAttributedString> GetAttributedStringAsync()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<NSAttributedString>();
            DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, options, out dict, ref error););
            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }
```